# Change variable name in loop

Tags: php, loops

```
$index = 0;

foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {

    $array + variable index number here = array('title' => $title);

    $index++;
}
```

I'm trying to change an array name depending on my index count. Is it possible to change variable name (ie. $array1, $array2 $array3 etc.) in the loop?

**Edit:**

After the loop has finished, I will generate a number number (depending on the count of $index) and then use this array... probably it's a stupid way of accomplishing what Im trying to do, but I don't have a better idea.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it isn't much clear what you're trying to do. Could you edit the question? What do you mean by "changing the variable's name" and why do you want to change it?

Comment: Dynamic variable names is never a good idea. Use an array instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try this instead:

```
$index = 0;

$arrays = array();

foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {

    $arrays[$index] = array('title' => $title);

    $index++;
}
```

While it is technically possible to do what you are asking, using an array of arrays will probably work better from you.

This type of indexing is exactly what arrays are designed for, you have a lot of items and want to be able to refer to them by number.

Unless you have a very specific reason to use the name of the variable to represent it's number you will probably have a much simpler time using it's index in the outer array.

Comment: if you wanted, the index could be the name as well, rather than a numbering.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can user an associate array.  Generating a string dynamically based on the iteration number and using that as a key in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable variables.  [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports Variable variables:

```
$num = 1;
$array_name = 'array' . $num;

$$array_name = array(1,2,3);

print_r($array1);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php